# Jest - Mocking a class from exported namespace

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to mock part of a TS project using Gremlin. I am using an external @types to use attach a type to it, but my issue appears to be tied to it using an exported namespace.
Here is the main flow:

1. mock 'process.GraphTraversalSource' class
2. mock 'process.GraphTraversal' class
3. have 'process.GraphTraversal' function 'V(...)' return mock of 'process.GraphTraversal'
4. have each method of 'process.GraphTraversal' return itself as needed

Problem:
Not seeing any example for dealing with mocking a class belonging to an exported namespace.
Will I just have to write a manual mock for both instances and just impl all extensions?

Versions:

- @types/gremlin - 3.4.6
- @types/jest - ^26.0.23
- jest - ^27.0.6
- ts-jest